# I want print pipe content to screen

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I want print the pipe content to screen.In particular I want that the father process print on the screen the pipe content that sent  the child process.I wrote a code but this not works very well.I have a segmentation fault error.Why?Thanks to everyone!

this is my code:

```
enter code here
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

int fd[2]; //File descriptor for the pipe;
pid_t P11; //Process child PID;
int status;
pipe(fd); //Make a pipe;

int buff[10000000000],i;

P11=fork();

if(P11<0){
printf("\nError\n");
exit(-1);
}

if(P11==0){
//This is the child process;
close(fd[0]);
dup2(fd[1],1);
close(fd[1]);
execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL);
          }
else{
close(fd[1]);
dup2(fd[0],0);
close(fd[0]);

read(0,&buff,sizeof(buff)); //Read the pipe content;
waitpid(P11,&status,0); //Wait the child process;

//Print the pipe content;
for(i=0;i<10000000000;i++)
printf("\nPrint: %c\n",buff[i]);

//Father's exec;
execlp("cd","cd"," ..",NULL);
     }

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I don't know of a machine where you can create a 40 GiB (approx — `int buff[10000000000]` is very, very, very big) buffer on the stack.  Most machines limit you to 1-8 MiB of stack — less than a thousandth of what you're trying to allocate.  If you really need 10 GiB, you'll need to allocate it dynamically.  I seriously doubt you need 10 GiB though; 64 KiB might quite enough.  (IIRC, you won't read more than `{PIPE_BUF}` bytes in a single `read()` call when the file descriptor is a pipe.  You'll need to trap how many bytes were read (return value from `read()`) and only process that many.)

Comment: It's right.Now I managed to solve the problem and the program prints what I wanted.Thanks so much!